# s.split('').?.? Ruby syntax

Tags: syntax

I am new to ruby on rails and started a tutorial and found out the following function

```
 def string_shuffle(s)
>>   s.split('').?.?
>> end
=> nil
>> string_shuffle("foobar")
```

What does  **`s.split('').?.?`** do? I know the split method but i have no idea what the two question marks are for. I saw "? used in boolean methods, but i couldnt understand how this one works. I tried to google it but, I couldnt find it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the tutorial in question:

> By replacing the question marks in Listing 4.10 with the appropriate
>   methods, combine split, shuffle, and join to write a function that
>   shuffles the letters in a given string.

Listing 4.10 is an exercise where the two question marks are meant to be replaced with actual method calls.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not valid

You can see split returns an array :
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split

And there is no method called ? in Array :
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

Comment: Reference: You can find it  here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby?version=3.2#sec:exercises

Comment: It is on Listing 4.10. It is ruby rails version 3 i think .

Comment: Those are exercises, you need to fill the blanks, you need to replace the ? with actual functions!